# Error Expected int but given string

Tags: java, bluej

I'm getting an error. It's saying that it's expecting an int, but i'm giving it a string. I'm not sure how to fix this.

```
int DNAstrandlength, strandDNA;
        Scanner DNAInfo = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("Please enter a DNA Strand!");
        strandDNA = DNAInfo.next();
        DNAstrandlength = strandDNA.length();
```

Comment: Please show how you declare those variables.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare strandDNA as `String`.

```
int DNAstrandlength;
String strandDNA;
Scanner DNAInfo = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println ("Please enter a DNA Strand!");
strandDNA = DNAInfo.next();
DNAstrandlength = strandDNA.length();
```

If you are reading an int then you have nextInt() from scanner.